# SharedPreferences not writing / reading

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, integer, sharedpreferences

We made a simple clicker game and I wanted to save the highscores in the SharedPreferences. So we wrote this code in MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("Highscore",clicks);
            editor.commit();
```

int clicks is the score you made that round.

In another activity, we wanted to display the Highscore in a TextView:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    highscore = sharedPrefs.getInt("Highscore",0);
    highscoretv.setText(Integer.toString(highscore));
```

But the highscore wasn't displayed. Have you an idea what I can do??????

Comment: `But the highscore wasn't displayed` what was displayed? `0`, being the default? Or do you get an error?

Comment: check if your `clicks`  holding the desired value or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` to just `MODE_PRIVATE` in both activities

Comment: [`MODE_PRIVATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) is just a constant that evaluates to `0`, this would not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this piece of code instead of `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `editor.commit()`; , you should use `editor.apply()`;
Apply will update the preference object instantly and will save the new values asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I solved it by myself. The Highscore was displayed in the Launcher Activity that was already open in the background. So as I closed the MainActivity, the LauncherActivity got in Foreground, but didn't update. Can you tell me if theres a thing like onActivityinForeground so I can prevent this?